# Right way to colorize ls?

Tags: command-line, grep, ls

Sometimes ago, I used Ubuntu and had colorized `ls`, `grep` "out of the box". Now I install  KUbuntu and `ls` is plain text by default.

I tried to discover something about it and notice that there is `/etc/skel/.bashrc`, which provide aliases to colorize `ls`, `grep` and something else, but seems it's not executed now.

What should I do to make it work?

Comment: what really counts is the .bashrc in your home directory.

Comment: when something is in skel, this just means that it'll get copied to the home directory of any new users you create

Comment: @josinalvo, there are no `~/.bashrc` file

Comment: copy the file from skel to your home, then, and open a new terminal, to see if it works

Comment: It works, post it as answer, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What really counts is the `.bashrc` in your home directory. When something is in `/etc/skel`, this just means that it'll get copied to the home directory of any new users you create

If there is no  .bashrc file in your home folder, copy the one from `/etc/skel` to your home. To see if it worked, you need to open a new terminal.